# How to get src path from TV image in ModX?

Tags: modx, modx-templates

The situtation is the following: I have a TV of image type called [*image-news*]. When I call it in a chunk it represents

```
<img src="assets/images/gallery/обследование(2).jpg">
```

Is there a way to get src-url of the template variable or to change its css-properties?

Answer (score 1):

Just change tv "output options" to text - [image: output options]

Comment: Generelly, it works. However, the problem is that I also want to use image TV as image output type, because I have a lot of web-pages where it is used that way. Is there another way to grab image source address?

Comment: `[[*imagetv:notempty=\`<img src="[[*imagetv]]">\`]]` - be enough?